# Finding and comparing stock prices at a specific day of every month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock, yfinance

So, the code I'm trying to make is solving for which days of the month would historically be the best days to  buy and sell a stock at. The stock I'm looking at in particular is UVXY. I'm trying to figure out which days would be the historical monthly lows and which ones would be the historical monthly highs, and average those out. The code I have so far isn't working because on some days of the month, the 20th or 10th isn't a trading day. The actual string would be much longer and have more dates, but I'm open to using yfinance to get the historical prices, I'm just not sure how it would work. Thanks!

> ```
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> ```

```
content = """
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
Fri 09-24-2021      22.22     22.27     20.38      20.49    47101392 
Thu 09-23-2021      22.52      22.63      21.32      21.48    48145436 
Wed 09-22-2021      24.88      25.37      22.88      23.68    59917888 
Tue 09-21-2021      26.03      28.18      25.20      25.86    73069928 
Mon 09-20-2021      26.26      30.81      25.36      27.31   104578920 
Fri 09-17-2021      21.56      23.58      21.33      23.48    61526336 
Thu 09-16-2021      21.91      22.66      21.04      21.38    42485960 
....
Wed 12-07-2016    9150.00    9390.00    8780.00    9270.00       37485 
Tue 12-06-2016    9530.00    9660.00    9130.00    9210.00       27220
</pre>""" 

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
stuff = soup.find('pre').text
lines = stuff.split("\n")

listOfStuff=[]
openPriceOfTrades=[]
closePriceOfTrades=[]
difference=[]



for line in lines:
  if(line[7:9]=="20"):
    closePriceOfTrades.append(line[20:-46])
  if line[7:9]=="10":
    openPriceOftrades.append(line[20:-46])
    difference = []   # initialization of result list

for i in range(len(openPriceOfTrades)-1):
  print(len(openPriceOfTrades))
  difference.append(float(closePriceOfTrades[i])-float(openPriceOfTrades[i]))
print(difference)
```

Comment: if you use `yfinance` then you should get data as JSON and I don't understand why you use `BeautifulSoup` for this.

Comment: maybe you should keep date as three columns `mont`, `day`, `year` - then it would be simpler to select data with the same day. And it would be much simpler if you would use `pandas.DataFrame` instead of normal lists.

Comment: your `content` looks like file CSV with spaces as separator and you could convert it to `pandas.DataFrame` using `io.StringIO` and `pandas.read_csv(... , sep='\s+')`

Answer (score 0):

You should learn `pandas.DataFrame`.

First I would remove lines with `<pre>` to have only data.

```
content = """
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
Fri 09-24-2021      22.22     22.27     20.38      20.49    47101392 
Thu 09-23-2021      22.52      22.63      21.32      21.48    48145436 
Wed 09-22-2021      24.88      25.37      22.88      23.68    59917888 
Tue 09-21-2021      26.03      28.18      25.20      25.86    73069928 
Mon 09-20-2021      26.26      30.81      25.36      27.31   104578920 
Fri 09-17-2021      21.56      23.58      21.33      23.48    61526336 
Thu 09-16-2021      21.91      22.66      21.04      21.38    42485960 
Wed 12-07-2016    9150.00    9390.00    8780.00    9270.00       37485 
Tue 12-06-2016    9530.00    9660.00    9130.00    9210.00       27220
</pre>"""

# remove lines with `<>`
content = '\n'.join(line for line in content.split('\n') if not line.startswith('<')).strip()

print(content)
```

and then it looks like file CSV with spaces as separator and you can use `io` to simulate file in memory and read it

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(content), sep='\s+', names=['day', 'date', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'volumen'])
```

and then you can create column with `date-day`

```
df['date-day'] = df['date'].str[3:5]
```

And then you can select all rows with `20` in column `date-day` and calculate `average` (mean)

```
day_20 = df[ df['date-day'] == '20' ]

print(day_20.mean())
```

Or you can use `groupby` to work with all days at the same time.

```
for value, group in df.groupby('date-day'):
    print('--- date-day:', value, '---')
    #print(group.mean())
    print('mean "A":', group['A'].mean())
    print('mean "B":', group['B'].mean())
    print('mean "C":', group['C'].mean())
    print('mean "D":', group['D'].mean())
```

---

Full working code:

```
content = """
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
Fri 09-24-2021      22.22     22.27     20.38      20.49    47101392 
Thu 09-23-2021      22.52      22.63      21.32      21.48    48145436 
Wed 09-22-2021      24.88      25.37      22.88      23.68    59917888 
Tue 09-21-2021      26.03      28.18      25.20      25.86    73069928 
Mon 09-20-2021      26.26      30.81      25.36      27.31   104578920 
Fri 09-17-2021      21.56      23.58      21.33      23.48    61526336 
Thu 09-16-2021      21.91      22.66      21.04      21.38    42485960 
Wed 12-07-2016    9150.00    9390.00    8780.00    9270.00       37485 
Tue 12-06-2016    9530.00    9660.00    9130.00    9210.00       27220
</pre>"""

# remove lines with `<>`
content = '\n'.join(line for line in content.split('\n') if not line.startswith('<')).strip()

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(content), sep='\s+', names=['day', 'date', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'volumen'])

df['date-day'] = df['date'].str[3:5]

print(df)

day_20 = df[ df['date-day'] == '20' ]
print(day_20)

for value, group in df.groupby('date-day'):
    print('--- date-day:', value, '---')
    #print(group.mean())
    print('mean "A":', group['A'].mean())
    print('mean "B":', group['B'].mean())
    print('mean "C":', group['C'].mean())
    print('mean "D":', group['D'].mean())
```

Result:

```
   day        date        A        B        C        D    volumen date-day
0  Fri  09-24-2021    22.22    22.27    20.38    20.49   47101392       24
1  Thu  09-23-2021    22.52    22.63    21.32    21.48   48145436       23
2  Wed  09-22-2021    24.88    25.37    22.88    23.68   59917888       22
3  Tue  09-21-2021    26.03    28.18    25.20    25.86   73069928       21
4  Mon  09-20-2021    26.26    30.81    25.36    27.31  104578920       20
5  Fri  09-17-2021    21.56    23.58    21.33    23.48   61526336       17
6  Thu  09-16-2021    21.91    22.66    21.04    21.38   42485960       16
7  Wed  12-07-2016  9150.00  9390.00  8780.00  9270.00      37485       07
8  Tue  12-06-2016  9530.00  9660.00  9130.00  9210.00      27220       06

   day        date      A      B      C      D    volumen date-day
4  Mon  09-20-2021  26.26  30.81  25.36  27.31  104578920       20

--- date-day: 06 ---
mean "A": 9530.0
mean "B": 9660.0
mean "C": 9130.0
mean "D": 9210.0
--- date-day: 07 ---
mean "A": 9150.0
mean "B": 9390.0
mean "C": 8780.0
mean "D": 9270.0
--- date-day: 16 ---
mean "A": 21.91
mean "B": 22.66
mean "C": 21.04
mean "D": 21.38
--- date-day: 17 ---
mean "A": 21.56
mean "B": 23.58
mean "C": 21.33
mean "D": 23.48
--- date-day: 20 ---
mean "A": 26.26
mean "B": 30.81
mean "C": 25.36
mean "D": 27.31
--- date-day: 21 ---
mean "A": 26.03
mean "B": 28.18
mean "C": 25.2
mean "D": 25.86
--- date-day: 22 ---
mean "A": 24.88
mean "B": 25.37
mean "C": 22.88
mean "D": 23.68
--- date-day: 23 ---
mean "A": 22.52
mean "B": 22.63
mean "C": 21.32
mean "D": 21.48
--- date-day: 24 ---
mean "A": 22.22
mean "B": 22.27
mean "C": 20.38
mean "D": 20.49
```

---

If you would use `yfinance` then you would get data directly as `pandas.DataFrame`